# default domain in routing for a rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that uses contraints which specify the domain, and take certain action depending on which (two are parked on the app).

After that action is taken - I'd like a default domain specified, so regardless of which domain was used while accessing the app, all relative links will only be using the default domain.

I.E. if myapp.com and mycoolapp.com both go to my app. I'd like all links within the app to use myapp.com even if they've accessed it using mycoolapp.com

Comment: So, you want to display content on mycoolapp.com, and all links on mycoolapp.com to go to myapp.com? An alternative is to redirect to myapp.com automatically if they request mycoolapp.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the domain in links, look at this: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

You should be able to implement it with the same approach, but changing out the domain where appropriate (by checking `request.domain`).